# Using "contains" to query a list <Key-Value> in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

In my code, I have "sourceElements" is a type of

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.
```

I need to query if the keys of this list contains a particular value and i tried this:

```
        sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("t","t"));
        sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test", "test"));
        sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("t1", "t2"));

        if (sourceElements.All(x => x.Key.Contains("test", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
             // do some stuff here
        }
```

but the compiler reports "type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage".

any ideas where things are not correct in the code?

Comment: You're checking a bool against `0`. `.contains` will return `true` or `false`

Comment: @NoLifeKing: yup. changed that!

Comment: Is it possible to change the datastructure to a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead?

Comment: When I tried this in LINQPad without `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` it worked without a problem

Comment: @NoLifeKing: great answer! that's what I was looking for! But again, this is ok if case-sensitive. what if I have to do a case insensitive "contains" ?

Comment: Just use `.ToLower()` on `Key` before checking.

Comment: @NoLifeKing: what difference does it make if I convert to a Dictionary ? Any advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should be functional (Doesn't give errors in LINQPad)

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> sourceElements = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("t","t"));
sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test", "test"));
sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("t1", "t2"));

if (sourceElements.All(x => x.Key.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("test")))
{
    // do some stuff here
}
```

So if you comment out the Keys with t and t1, the code within the `if`-block will execute

Comment: Thanks for the answer.what difference does it make if I convert my list to a Dictionary ? Any advantages?

Comment: No big difference really. Just easier to add values (According to me) Since it would be `sourceElements.Add("t", "t");` instead. And Dictionaries must contain unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the if statement be:

```
if(sourceElements.All(x => x.Key.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("test"))
{
     // do some stuff here
}
```

`Contains` will return `true` or `false`, not an integer.

Comment: There is no overload of `Contains` on `String` which accepts these argument types

Comment: @DGibbs: thanks! worked. only i have to add a "tolower" as NolifeKing said. (I' m not the downvoter anyway)

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. No problem, happy to help. Only reason I can imagine it was downvoted was because of the missing case insensitive search but this was not mentioned in your OP and only noticed after reading the comments.

Comment: @DGibbs i did comment. The overload of `Contains` you had in the original version of your answer didn't exist (only one available is `String::Contains(string)`).  I removed the downvote once you updated your answer.

Comment: @JaredPar That was simply a mistake copied from the OP's question. But thankyou for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that there is no method `Contains` on `String` which takes those argument types.  There is only one overload of `Contains` and it takes a single argument of type `String`.

I believe you are looking for the method `Index(string, StringComparison)`

```
if (sourceElements.All(x => x.Key.IndexOf("test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))
```

If you want the original code to work you could add an extension method which gives `String` the appearance of having such an overload.

```
bool Contains(this string str, string value, StringComparison comp) {
  return str.IndexOf(value, comp) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely! thanks for the answer. but, in my case, how I do use "contains" then? IndexOf works great but need to know how to use contains to check if my string is in it or not?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed when `IndexOf` returns a value that is `>= 0` then it contains the string you searched for

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> sourceElements = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("t", "t"));
        sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("test", "test"));
        sourceElements.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("t1", "t2"));

        if (sourceElements.All(x =>x.Key.Contains("test")))
        {
            // do some stuff here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Examples of linq all operator](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/linq-all-operator/)

The solutions described are useful, but in my case i had to check if any one element contains the key instead of all. So i used the method
`if(!lst.Any(x => x.Key.Contains("Internal"))){ lst.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Internal", "Internal"));}`
which is .Any(); so it will check the entire list if the value exists or not